# Phonegap, jQuery ajax post not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, file-upload, cordova

I have following client code to upload image from phone

```
$("#placeorder").click(
 function() {
  if ($('#placeorderform').valid()) {
   var formData = $('#placeorderform').serialize();
   formData += "&uploaded="+ imgData;
   $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : _host+ "/addorder.php",
    data : formData,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success : onSuccess,
    error : onError
    });
  }
 });
```

Server Side PHP (Not Working)

```
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['uploaded']);
```

Server Side PHP ($_REQUEST or $_GET works; But for small images)

```
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$_REQUEST['uploaded']);
```

what is the problem with my client code.

## Additional observations:

I tried to inspect the request header and found surprising result. When i do above ajax in browser the data is received in POST. But from within Phonegap, even after explicit mention of type : "POST" the data is received in GET.

Can someone put some light on these behaviors :( Something wrong with my Phonegap configuration?

Comment: If it only works for 'small images' then your client side code is fine - it sounds more like a filesize limit is being imposed on your post.

Comment: Thanks. But post fails for same images; which works when get or request type is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i got this working...Surprising find !!!

when i change dataType: 'jsonp' to ('json' or 'text') the formdata goes through in $_POST.

Only when the dataType: 'jsonp' the formdata for some unknow reasons goes through $_GET or $_REQUEST

Don't know why this must be happening; But for now my problem is resolved with 'json'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know serialising the form does not include files. If you are using PhoneGap why don't you use the File API they provide which lets you upload files?

In order to send form variables along with the file, just add a params array with the options

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="text/plain";

var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
```

Comment: Along with the file to be uploaded, I need to submit form data to a single a php file. Can i send serialized form data along with file to upload using FileTransfer API in Phonegap?

Comment: I have tried this but still not working. Seems some issue with my Andriod project configuration. ft.upload(), $.post() and $.get() none of these make a server call neither their respective success and error callback functions get called. Only $.ajax() works but data is received in $_GET not $_POST

Comment: Seems like it might be a problem with your PHP code. Have you tested the form post through a simple HTML form?

Comment: yes, have tested creating simple html form; post works here. only when called from my ajax code the post gets nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to send a POST request while expecting a JSONP in response. As JSONP are merely get requests, which embed scripts returned into your dom.

This is how ajax calls work in jquery, and this also explains--
*'even after explicit mention of type : "POST" the data is received in GET'*